# Difference between char *foo vs (char *)foo in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax, pointers

What is the difference between

```
char *foo
```

and

```
(char *) foo
```

in Objective-C?

Here is an example for both scenarios: 
1. `@interface Worker: NSObject { char *foo; }` 
2. `- initWithName:(char *)foo`

Comment: Add a little more context. Full Objective-C expressions that use this form.

Comment: Here is an example for both scenarios:

1. @interface Worker: NSObject
   {
     char *foo;
    }

2. - initWithName:(char *)foo

Comment: It's probably worth checking out Peter Hosey's excellent "Everything you need to know about pointers in C": http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Answer (score 6):

There are two places your first expression can appear.  The first is as a variable definition.  By itself, `char *foo` is defining a variable -  a pointer to `char` named `foo`.  In the context of a function definition it defines the type of one of the function's parameters:

```
void function(char *foo)
```

Declares a function that takes a single `char *` argument and indicates that that argument will be referred to by the name `foo` in the context of the function.

There are also a couple of explanations for your other expression.  The first is in the case of a method definition, which is similar to the function declaration above:

```
- (void)method:(char *)foo
```

Declares an instance method taking a single argument, in this case of type `char *` and named `foo`.  It could also appear as the return type of the method:

```
- (char *)foo
```

Another case is as a typecast:

```
void *foo;
char *bar = (char *)foo;
```

In which case the expression typecasts `foo` from a void pointer to a `char` pointer and assigns the value to `bar`.

Edit:

For your particular examples:

```
@interface Worker: NSObject
{
    char *foo;
}
```

This example is declaring an instance variable named `foo`.  It has type `char *`.

```
- initWithName:(char *)foo
```

This example is declaring an instance method taking one parameter named `foo` of type `char *`.

Comment: I understand instance variable vs methods. What confuses me is the naming conventions (semantics?) They are both type char *.

Is this just the way that instance variables and method parameters of type char * are declared?

Comment: @iWalter, yeah it's just syntax.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I needed that clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (char*) foo; // "static" function returning a variable of type char*
- (char*) foo; // member function returning a variable of type char*


// ...
{
    // ...
    char* foo; // variable of type char*
    // ...
}
// ...
```

**EDIT**

```
- (void) whatever: (char*)foo; // member function, with 
                               // parameter foo of type char*

// ...
{
    // ...
    char* bar = (char*) foo; // casting variable foo to type char* 
    // ...
}
// ...
```